# Movie where zombie talks on the phone to people in a house and tells them the coast is clear

Tags: story-identification, movie, zombie

I can remember a zombie talks on the phone to people in a house, and tells them it is all clear, and to come on out. They ask him who the current president is.

Answer (score 7):

*[Return of the Living Dead Part II](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/ReturnOfTheLivingDeadPartII)* (TV Tropes link)

> A particularly clever zombie almost lures the protagonists into a trap, until Dr. Mandel asks him who the current president is. Having been dead for years, if not decades, he has no idea

Found with a search for *film zombie telephone "current president"*

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: Didn't one of the other "living Dead" movies also have a zombie police officer grabbing the police radio in a car and saying "Send more cops"?  That one made me laugh.

Comment: "Send more paramedics". The first *Return of the Living Dead*.